# What's the most efficient way to modify multiple lines of text in Vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

Let's say I have a text file called `index.html.slim` that looks like this:

```
- if post.published?
    section.post
    h1 = post.title
    p = post.description
    a = link_to 'Read more', post
```

What I'd like to do is indent the last 3 lines so that the file looks like this:

```
- if post.published?
    section.post
      h1 = post.title
      p = post.description
      a = link_to 'Read more', post
```

**What's the most efficient way to do this in Vim?**

Right now to do this I would go to line 3 with `3  return`, `i` to enter insert mode, `spacebar` twice to indent two characters and then `esc` to exit insert mode. To do this on line 4 and 5 I would move down with `j` and press `.` followed and then `wq` to save.

That's a total of 10 keystrokes. I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this; however, I'm not sure what the best method is.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to select column and then insert 2 spaces for last 3 lines.

- Move cursor to character `h`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to change to selection mode
- move cursor 2 down using <kbd>j</kbd> twice
- press <kbd>I</kbd> (capital i) to change to insert mode
- now press <kbd>space</kbd> twice and hit <kbd>esc</kbd> and press any other key like <kbd>j</kbd>, that should do it.

Comment: @AndrewHendrie Did you press esc after 2 spaces? Try pressing any other key like `j` after you hit esc. I just tried it and it works.

Comment: right on - it works. moved me from 10 keystrokes down to 7. I still think there's got to be a more efficient way to do this though...

Comment: @AndrewHendrie Well, if there were lets say 100 lines you wanted to indent you could just do `G` instead of moving cursor down using `j`. That would save you lots of keystokes.